# How to modify xml declaration in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to modify processing instructions in a source xml with XSLT, for example:

**XML INPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

</root>
```

**XML OUTPUT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
<root>

</root>
```

Can I do this with XSLT?
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is cannot be configured inside XSLT by itself, but it can be configured in XSLT-processor (depending on which you used), can you provide more details about your XSLT-processor?

Comment: The XSLT-processor is SAXParse

Answer (score 1):

That is the XML declaration, it is not a processing instruction. If you want a particular output encoding then use e.g. `<xsl:output encoding="Windows-1252"/>`. But any XML parser is required to support UTF-8 so using an 8-bit code page in the age of Unicode and XML does not improve interoperability.

Comment: As a child of `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform`. You realize there is a public spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#output you could check, do you?

Comment: I not want a particular output encoding. I want that the first line of XML document is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>

Comment: encoding="..." *is* about the encoding. trying to set it to something without actually using that encoding means producing erroneous XML, and XML tools will not really help you to do that.